# Codeigniter don't load changes made in the source code

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created an online inventory system with a downloaded template. At first, I can see all my codes is being reflected in the view page but after some time no matter what I added or change in my code nothing happens to the view even though I already put header no cache and many times I cleared the browser history and pressed ctrl+F5. Now I am stuck to the view page from last 3 days and I already made so many changes in my source code. Please help......

Comment: I even restore the whole folder to previous version that is editable but same results everything that I changed nothing is reflected to the view page.....

Comment: Sorry my bad I forgot that I created an extra folder and in their I copy the header and footer and that is the one I always edit but the header for my website was in the common page. Sorry....

Comment: What have you tried? Let's see some code. What exactly is going wrong? Do you get any errors? What are those errors? What have you tried to do to fix those errors? What happened when you did that? Remember to include these things when you make your question. Follow this guide to make sure your questions are of high quality: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask